# LEFT JOIN with a specific condition

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables

```
table A
---------
uid   c1(distinct)
---------
 1     a
 1     b
 2     c
 3     d
 3     e
 3     f
 4     g
```

and

```
table B
---------
uid   c2(non unique)
---------
 1     x
 2     y
 3     z
 3     z  
 3     v
```

I need a resultant table which maps table A to table B on uid like this

```
Result Table
-------------
uid   c1   c2
-------------
 1     a    x
 1     b    -
 2     c    y
 3     d    z
 3     e    z
 3     f    v
 4     g    -
```

Basically once a row from table B is used in the resultant table, it must be exhausted.
None of the JOINS work in this case.

Both these tables contain large number of records, so I can't write individual queries for each uid.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "None of the JOINS work in this case"?  What you're describing is a left outer join from what I see.

Comment: @Jens But a left join would give me the row 1 b x right?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want `1 b x` ? Or, why would you want `1 b a` as opposed to `1 b x`?

Comment: Show us your query please

Comment: @Strawberry I simplified the question as to my requirement.So once a row from tableB is used, it must be exhausted and should not appear in the resultant table.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is impossible since it requires matching impossible criteria together ("row number" which differs anyways between `tableA` and `tableB`), as the uid is not unique.

Comment: table b needs a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Does table b have a primary key? I'm assuming it's UID listed is a foreign key for table a, but does it have it's own primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's count the rows with the same uid and join equal uids and that numbers

```
select t.uid, c1, ifnull(c2, '-') c2 
    from 
      (select *, @n:=if(@i=uid, @n+1, if(@i:=uid, 1, 1)) n 
           from tableA 
               cross join 
                (select @n:=0, @i:='') param1 
          order by uid
      ) t 
    left join 
      (select *, @n1:=if(@i1=uid, @n1+1, if(@i1:=uid, 1, 1)) n1 
           from tableB 
               cross join 
                (select @n1:=0, @i1:='') param2 
         order by uid
      ) tt 
          on t.uid=tt.uid and t.n=tt.n
```

Comment: there ya go. Variables

Comment: I think it would be safer if the variables had a different name in each subquery.  I think this is important for initialization reasons . . . MySQL might initialize all variables at the same time and then do the subqueries.  In any case, this looks like the right approach in MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok. now will  change